# Python Requests Session Setting Cookie Key Error

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting the cookies from selenium first after logging in and then adding the cookies to a requests session object. I get a key error and I don't understand why. Here is my code:

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    for key, value in cookie.items():
        s.cookies.set(cookie[key], cookie[value])
```

Cookie looks like this:
`{'domain': '.domain.com', 'expiry': 1666302866, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__utmb', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '233684620.3.10.1666301065'}` 
The error in question is KeyError: '.domain.com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for key, value in cookie.items():
    s.cookies.set(cookie[key], cookie[value])
```

Since you are already iterating over the key-value pairs, `cookie[value]` makes no sense and is bound to fail, and `cookie[key]` gives back the value, not the key.

You need

```py
for key, value in cookie.items():
    s.cookies.set(key, value)
```

Comment: Thank you! Will mark as solution when it's possible. I can't believe I have become so blind to my own code, been sitting to long with the application in question.